# Robocopy to copy files and folders to and fro between a location on Windows and UNIX

Tags: linux, windows, unix, robocopy

Using Robocopy to copy / move files and folders from one Windows server to another is pretty much a possibility. But can Robocopy be used to do the same across different OS ? i.e. transfer files from Windows to UNIX / Linux or from Linux / UNIX to Windows ?

If yes then what kind of permissions do I need to set?

P.S.: The folder will be shared between these OS

Comment: You need a shared folder robocopy is able to do its work on.It will only be able to access what's in that folder or the machine it's run on. You can't run robocopy on Linux. You will have to look into something like `rsync` if there is stuff to be done on the Linux machine that is not exposed by the share.

Comment: My robocopy command would be running on the Windows only. So by what you are saying I will be able to copy files from Windows to Linux ?

Comment: By setting up a share. Setup a shared folder that both system are able to access. You probably will have to look into `samba` for this and how to provide a share on the Linux machine.